# NotifyIcon showing message from program

Tags: c#, notifyicon

Just wondering if there is a way to display a message from the notifyicon when a certain event in the program is reached. Almost like a balloon popup. I cant seem to find anything online... This would be used to alert the user to a certain event in the program.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use notify icon:

```
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        notifyIcon1.Icon = new Icon(SystemIcons.Application, 40, 40);
        notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
```

Much like you can use the BallonTip member of the it:

```
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "The quick brown fox. Jump!";
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle ="Alert!";
        notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(500);
```

You can use everytime certain event or condition is meet, you can always have the `ShowBalloonTip` method call.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you use WPF or not, but here is some great code I found a while back that allows you to do a whole lot with notifications.  I believe you can use it in Winforms as well.

http://www.hardcodet.net/projects/wpf-notifyicon

If you want to pay for something (or you already have it), part of the Telerik suite includes a DesktopAlert feature:

http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/desktopalert.aspx